# How to resolve duplicate assigned IPs local network

Tags: ssh, dhcp

setup:
I have six linux embedded software-defined radios (SDR) all connected to a wireless local network. The only way to log into one of these SDRs is to SSH into it through a remote computer. IPv4 set to Automatic (DHCP). Remote device is an ubuntu 16.04.

**The problem is**, IP addresses are being assigned to 2 or possibly more SDRs and because of that, when I try to sign in using `ssh root@foo`, it will sign me into another SDR on the network (say `root@bar`). Or it just won't let me sign in at all. What's even more odd is when I use `nmap` to check how many devices are on my network, it gives me inconsistent results (sometimes 3, sometimes 4 devices connected out of the six).

I'm thinking something is going on with SSH keys or something with DHCP.

Edit: When trying to ssh into an SDR using it's appropriate hostname, I get:
      `ssh: could not resolve hostname [hostname]: Name or service not known`
      even though I've been able to connect to it before.

Comment: It sounds like one or more SDRs are not getting their IPs from DHCP ("hard-wired" IP), or the SDRs are not registering themselves with DNS properly (which could lead to "legacy" DNS records pointing to the wrong IP). You might want to give some thought toward creating reservations in DHCP to ensure that a given SDR always gets the same IP from DHCP.

Comment: Subsequent to your edit, it looks even more like it's the second possibility - DNS registration failure. Consider reservations, and if you can't get them to register properly, either manually add them to DNS, or add entries to your `HOSTS` file.

Comment: Are you referring to ssh known hosts? I was hoping to resolve the problem without reservations because I may get access to many more SDRs and creating reservations for all might not be the right way to go for the future of the project. Any ideas where I should look to solve this DNS problem?

Comment: ssh `known_hosts` might be a possibility as well, but I was thinking of the OS [`etc/hosts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). Unless you expect to have more SDRs than available addresses in your netblock, I'm not sure I see why you would feel that reservations is nonviable - in the enterprise I work for, that's exactly how we're handling certain shared resources.